# CCSequence like CCSpawn use functions from different classes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, sequence, spawn

I try to use a few functions in my GameLayer. First - from another class, second - from GameLayer class, but CCSequence run like CCSpawn, not sequence. Separately they both work perfect in GameLayer.

in GameLayer

```
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                    [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self.rolypoly selector:@selector(jumpToDeath:)],
                    [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToGameOverLayer:tagName:)data:(int)TagGameOverLose],     
                     nil]];
```

in rolypoly class

```
-(void)jumpToDeath:(id)sender
{

       [self.sprite stopAllActions];

       id actionSpaw = [CCSpawn actions:
                       [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x, self.sprite.position.y+self.sprite.contentSize.height)],
                       [CCBlink actionWithDuration:1.0f blinks:4],
                        nil];

       [self.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                              [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setJumpingToDeath:withValue:)data:(void*)1],
                              actionSpaw,
                              [CCHide action],
                              [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveSpriteDeath)], 
                              nil]];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that the `runAction` is not a blocking method. Meaning that when you use a function call action (like `CCCallFunc`) the action after it in the sequence will be executed when the function call returns. In your case `jumpToDeath` runs actions but does not wait for them to be finished and when it returns the second action in your main sequence is executed (before the sequence inside `jumpToDeath` is finished)

Try to rearrange your actions. If you need more help let me know.

**EDIT :** My suggestion :

```
 [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                    [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self.rolypoly selector:@selector(jumpToDeath:)], nil]];

-(void)jumpToDeath:(id)sender
{

       [self.sprite stopAllActions];

       id actionSpaw = [CCSpawn actions:
                       [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x, self.sprite.position.y+self.sprite.contentSize.height)],
                       [CCBlink actionWithDuration:1.0f blinks:4],
                        nil];

       [self.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                              [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setJumpingToDeath:withValue:)data:(void*)1],
                              actionSpaw,
                              [CCHide action],
                              [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveSpriteDeath)],
                              [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goToGameOverLayer:tagName:)data:(int)TagGameOverLose],
                              nil]];
}
```

As you can see I moved the last call function action to be the last in the `jumpToDeath` method which insures it will be executed last after all other actions are done.

I do not know what is the implementation of `moveSpriteDeath` but if it does not contain actions than it will be ok, otherwise show its implementation or try doing the same

Comment: all I can advise in this case is use [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3], between actions